# converting time that is an int in HHMM format and creating an hour field from it using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following image.

[image: dataframe]
This is what df.head().df.dict() produces:

[image: df.head().df.dict()]

The Time Occurred field is a time field in the HHMM format but datatype is int. I'd like to create a new field "Hour" from the "Time Occurred" field which only shows the hour. For instance, where '450' I'd have '4' in the hour field. I tried the following code:

```
s = df['Time Occurred'].astype(str)
df['Hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:], unit='h')
```

But I get the following error:
ValueError: unit must not be specified if the input contains a str

I found several posts on stack that addressed extracting time from datetime but this isn't the issue I'm trying to solve for

Comment: @enke I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.zfill`:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 450, 2320, 545, 350, 2100])
pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str).str.zfill(4), format="%H%M")
```

Output:

```
0   1900-01-01 00:01:00
1   1900-01-01 04:50:00
2   1900-01-01 23:20:00
3   1900-01-01 05:45:00
4   1900-01-01 03:50:00
5   1900-01-01 21:00:00
```

Explain:

- `str.zfill(n)` pads zeros on the left of its inputs; so your *ints* become a *string* with at most 4 digits.

  ```
  0    0001
  1    0450
  2    2320
  3    0545
  4    0350
  5    2100
  ```
- `pd.to_datetime` then uses the *string* to parse based on `format`, i.e. HHMM (`%H%M`).

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will help. Its option `format` enables to convert a string with a given format into a datetime. We parse "HHMM" using `format='%H%M` (see [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) package).

To answer the question:

```
# a toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time Occurred': {0:'450', 1:'2320', 2:'545'}})
# parse the date
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Occurred'], format='%H%M')
# make new columns
df['Hours'] = date.dt.hour
df['Minutes'] = date.dt.minute

print(df)

  Time Occurred  Hours  Minutes
0           450      4       50
1          2320     23       20
2           545      5       45
```

Note that you can also parse date strings into datetime objects using `datetime.strptime`.

Comment: I tried that approach but got the following error: time data '1' does not match format '%H%M' (match)

Comment: @ThatGuyXY this example is working fine. Please give a toy dataframe as text (and not image) if you need more help.